# Motion detection using only video clips

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, conv-neural-network

I am trying to do motion detection of whether the person is walking or running. However I got only 40 short video clips of a single person walking or running. How to do the motion detection using video data? Can anyone please specify or point to any papers or implementation.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV has many trackers (https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d9/df8/group__tracking.html). For instance: `cv2.TrackerKCF_create()`.

You may find some comprehensive tutorials on the subject, like this one: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/09/21/opencv-track-object-movement/